# How to encrypt a file and hide password

Tags: c++, file, encryption, passwords

Our company is selling car motors. If sold motor gets broken, we want client (that motor's owner) to run our application, which reads data from motor and saves it in a file. My job is to write this application.

My problem is file security. If file is stored in plain text, client can change it with no problem, and we won't realize it (we could only really know the authencity of that data if client sends that motor to us phisically and we run the application ourselves - which costs time and money). So I supposed I need to encrypt the file, maybe with AES encryption.

Now the (sub)problem becomes how to store password for encryption. A bit of googling told me it basically can't be done in 100% safe manner. The only thing that can be used is obfuscation, like white box cryptography. Which isn't safe, and our clients will have big motivation to crack it.

So now I am stuck trying to find some proper solution. I wonder if far more knowledgable people from Stackoverflow can advise me on how to solve my problem.

Comment: Sounds like a typical usecase for public-key-cryptography. Create a RSA-keypair, encrypt the data with the public key that is shipped with your application, decrypt with the private key kept at your company.

Comment: Use hardware dongles or take a look if your ECU has a safe storage for passwords.

Comment: Why does it have to be a plain text file? Perhaps a simple in-app database (like e.g. SQLite) could be used instead? What kind of data are you saving? How much data? And do you really think ordinary users will go into the data file (text or not) and attempt to modify it? If they do and corrupts the file or input inaccurate data, that's the problem of your customer and not you. You could save time by adding a non-modification clause to the contract the customers sign to buy your software.

Comment: Whatever you do DON'T try and create your own secure encryption scheme. Use an industry accepted standard; Obfuscation is not security. As suggested by @piet.t some form of public-key infrastructure would be a good approach

Comment: This question may get a better response on the [security exchange](https://security.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: I think this is a bit too broad. It is an interesting question but it is a bit undefined. Why store a file on the customer computer that they can't see? Will the application need to keep editing and changing that file? Are you just dumping the data to transmit to a server? Etc...

Comment: Why not just add a hash code to the file. That should detect tampering, not sure you really need full blown encryption.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only safe way to achieve this is to generate and sign the data in a trusted environment. An application running on the client's PC is generally not running in a trusted environment. If you can trust the motor (I guess it runs some kind of firmware which you can communicate with), the motor should generate and sign the file and your application should simply pass it on.

Btw: Do not confuse encryption with signing. If you encrypt a file, you make sure that nobody else can read it, but there is no guarantee against manipulation. If you sign a file, you protect it against manipulation. If you want both (protect against manipulation and prevent unauthorised reading), you have to encrypt and sign. The logic of encryption and signing is kind of reverse: Signing is done with a private key (verification possible by anyone having the public key). Encryption is done with a public key (readying only possible by anyone having the private key). This also shows you your trust issue: For signing you have to deliver the private (sic!) key to your client. You need measures to prevent extraction of this private key. This is fundamentally impossible without special hardware.

Also: Make a different private key for each client/motor. Even with special hardware someone might be able to extract that key. If it is the same for all motors, your security is broken for all motors.

Answer (score 0):

What data are you extracting from the motor?
OBD port?
Proprietary?

If you don't want your code to be easily reversed,
you may consider hardware
https://www.google.com/search?q=encryption+ic&tbs=qdr:y

For even more security,
I'd recommend a man-in-the middle approach;
they send you data (by email, etc),
then you have a batch process,
on a separate server/network
to compare data.
Customer feedback goes back out the same way.
Customer never knows what IP network everything is saved upon.

Answer (score 0):

As already mention by other pals, you are gonna need asymmetric encryption with 2 distinct keys for encipherment and decipherment. Thus AES as a symmetrical encryption system won't help. The terms "public"and "private" are subjective, meaning that every1 may know about the public key but no1 except a special person knows the private key. Those terms IMHO do not apply to your case; both keys are private according to your application. I prefer to call them "server" and "client" key for this project, and server refers to maintenance servant, while client is the motor ECU.
Main problem you are facing is the possiblity of exposing the client key via downloading the microcontroller/FPGA firmware by a hacker. Assuming RS232 connection for firmware [up/down]load or upgrade, you need to guard against unauthorized firmware manipulation. You are gonna have to investigate the task of modifying the firmware loader to use one-time-password for authentication over RS232, before every firmware transfer; the intent of authentication is to identify an authorize the legal maintenance agent. Since firmware manipulation is done in factory - using a direct wired connection - there is no risk of a man-in-the-middle attack.

Comment: "every1"?!?  "no1"?!?!  Is this a text message?